# OpenERP 7 and Base Report Designer

Tags: odoo, openoffice.org, openerp-7

I'm having difficulties with Base Report Designer for OpenERP 7.

First of all, I can only make it work with Openoffice and not with Libreoffice.

Then, when using OpenOffice connected to an OpenERP 7 local database, it takes forever to retrieve the fields and sometimes it just freezes and doesn't retrieve them.

Has anyone had these issues? Any idea how to overcome them?

Comment: which version of LibreOffice Write you use? Might be sometime it's freezes

Comment: i've never warmed up with the designer, its output was so horrible when you know how to do the rml the way you like to do. besides, i had the same problems with libreoffice. maybe @luckbo's "answer" is the only answer :-/